# Unable to fetch IAP from App Store causing app to fail

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, swiftui

I am trying to implement in App Purchases in a simple app I am creating.
I have a model method that is supposed to get the products using the productID. However the products array shown below returns an empty array. This causes the app to crash when trying to purchase an in app purchase.

[I have followed a modified version of a tutorial I found online.](https://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchases-guide/) But have not been able to figure out why mine doesn't work.

The Github repository for the project can be found [here.](https://github.com/tbraun1551/ColorGuesser)

```
class Model {

var products = [SKProduct]()

func getProduct(containing keyword: String) -> SKProduct? {
    print("The array of SKProducts in Model getProduct is \(products)")
    let test = products.filter { $0.productIdentifier.contains(keyword) }.first
    print(test)
    return test
}
```

}

Comment: Have you configured in-app purchases within your apps entitlements & on the apple dev website?

Comment: As far as I can tell yes. I uploaded a copy to GitHub here. https://github.com/tbraun1551/ColorGuesser